# Config.h - No such file or directory

Tags: c

The file 'safe-read.c' include the lib 'config.h', where is placed this file?

I've found many files with this name in the libs, but I don't know what the right one.

UPDATE

I've my file with:

```
...
#include <safe-read.h>
#include <safe-read.c>
...
```

in the file *safe-read.c* there's this include block

```
#include <config.h> //line 19

/* Specification.  */
#ifdef SAFE_WRITE
# include "safe-write.h"
#else
# include "safe-read.h"
#endif

/* Get ssize_t.  */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <errno.h>

#ifdef EINTR
# define IS_EINTR(x) ((x) == EINTR)
#else
# define IS_EINTR(x) 0
#endif

#include <limits.h>

#ifdef SAFE_WRITE
# define safe_rw safe_write
# define rw write
#else
# define safe_rw safe_read
# define rw read
# undef const
# define const /* empty */
#endif
```

When I compile my file I've the following error:

> file: X/Y/gnulib/lib/safe-read.c line: 19 message: fatal error:
>   config.h: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to specify what you are trying to compile (what library) - add it as a tag to your question. Most likely the config.h is generated for a configuration tool - try check out any configure scripts in the libs build directory.

Comment: Why are you so convinced you need safe-read.c? Do you know what purpose it's intended to serve?

Comment: I know that there are better ways, but it is a constraint of the project for the moment. It's a school project and the professor want it and he is not very quick to respond to students questions.

Answer (score 21):

`config.h` is normally generated by the `./configure` script to reflect the target system's characteristics. In your case, it's tied into the whole gnulib "let's replace all the system's library functions with out own hacks" mess, so a lot of what's in a gnulib project `config.h` is stuff that gnulib's portion of `configure` generated.

Answer (score 3):

You’re probably missing the libconfig-dev package from your system. Simply run the following command and it’ll fix it:

> sudo apt-get install libconfig-dev

Comment: If you're getting: "giommconfig.h: No such file or directory" also try this item.